# Numba error "sequence item 0: expected str instance, type found"

Tags: python, regression, numba

I want to select variables in multiple regression analysis.
I tried to use this code http://planspace.org/20150423-forward_selection_with_statsmodels/.
The problem is that I want to select from 50 variables and it takes too much time. I've used Numba to make it faster and wrote the following code:

```
@jit
def forward_selected(data, response):
"""Linear model designed by forward selection.

Parameters:
-----------
data : pandas DataFrame with all possible predictors and response

response: string, name of response column in data

Returns:
--------
model: an "optimal" fitted statsmodels linear model
       with an intercept
       selected by forward selection
       evaluated by adjusted R-squared
"""
remaining = set(data.columns)
remaining.remove(response)
selected = [str]
current_score, best_new_score = 0.0, 0.0
while remaining and current_score == best_new_score:
    scores_with_candidates = [str]
    for candidate in remaining:
        formula = "{} ~ {} + 1".format(response,
                                       ' + '.join(selected + [candidate]))
        score = smf.ols(formula, data).fit().rsquared_adj
        scores_with_candidates.append((score, candidate))
    scores_with_candidates.sort()
    best_new_score, best_candidate = scores_with_candidates.pop()
    if current_score < best_new_score:
        remaining.remove(best_candidate)
        selected.append(best_candidate)
        current_score = best_new_score
formula = "{} ~ {} + 1".format(response,
                               ' + '.join(selected))
model = smf.ols(formula, data).fit()
return model

model = forward_selected(df, col)
```

But it returns the following error:

> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, type found

Please, tell me how to fix it. If you don't understand my question, I will be glad to give more information in comments.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "~/PycharmProjects/anacondaenv/touhu_1.py", line 164, in
>
> submit = forecast(col)
>
> File "~/PycharmProjects/anacondaenv/touhu_1.py", line 75, in forecast
>
> model = forward_selected(df, col)
> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, type found

Comment: One of the most helpful tools in debugging is the traceback.  Please provide it.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that using numba for this function is going to improve its performance since I'm guessing most of the work is done by statsmodels, which Numba can't doing anything with. Typically Numba can only speed-up functions that are doing pure scalar or array based operations. If there is data preparation that fits into that narrow focus area, then I would separate it out and then pass it to statsmodels in a different function.

Comment: Thank you and your comments. If you know the way to select variables, tell me that.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the best ways to see if `numba` really works as booster is to try the `njit` instead of the `jit` decorator. `njit` forces `no-python-mode` and breaks if anything falls back to python (which offers no speed-benefit at all). Short answer: Don't use anything except `np.ndarrays`. So no strings, no tuple, no lists and *NO* calls to un-jitted functions.

So I have fixed the error: numba does not allow empty lists in the main function body ... not sure why (maybe a bug?!) But it works if you move it inside the `while` block.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import numba as nb

@nb.jit
def forward_selected_nojit(data, response):
    """Linear model designed by forward selection.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    data : pandas DataFrame with all possible predictors and response

    response: string, name of response column in data

    Returns:
    --------
    model: an "optimal" fitted statsmodels linear model
           with an intercept
           selected by forward selection
           evaluated by adjusted R-squared
    """
    remaining = set(data.columns)
    remaining.remove(response)
    selected = None  # Changed this line
    current_score, best_new_score = 0.0, 0.0
    while remaining and current_score == best_new_score:
        if selected is None:  # Changed this and next line
            selected = []
        scores_with_candidates = []
        for candidate in remaining:
            formula = "{} ~ {} + 1".format(response,
                                           ' + '.join(selected + [candidate]))
            score = smf.ols(formula, data).fit().rsquared_adj
            scores_with_candidates.append((score, candidate))
        scores_with_candidates.sort()
        best_new_score, best_candidate = scores_with_candidates.pop()
        if current_score < best_new_score:
            remaining.remove(best_candidate)
            selected.append(best_candidate)
            current_score = best_new_score
    formula = "{} ~ {} + 1".format(response,
                                   ' + '.join(selected))
    model = smf.ols(formula, data).fit()
    return model
```

That could probably be solved in a better way but the important thing here is the timings. But first check if numba does make any strange stuff:

```
# With numba
sl ~ rk + yr + 1
0.835190760538

# Without numba
sl ~ rk + yr + 1
0.835190760538
```

so the results are the same now let's see how they perform:

```
# with numba
10 loops, best of 3: 264 ms per loop

# without numba
10 loops, best of 3: 252 ms per loop
```

So it's exactly like I expected. Using python types and calling unjitted external functions and you don't get any speed gain. You can probably make it faster with numba but make sure you read through the numba documentation and see what is supported: [Python types](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.23.1/reference/pysupported.html) and [Numpy Types](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.23.1/reference/numpysupported.html)